# Regex Expression to allow underscore,hyphen and '&' symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex Expression to allow alphanumeric and special characters `'-','_','&'` only.
I have tried this Regex but it is not working !

```
var testexp=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_&]+$/;
```

Comment: Try to escape them: `\-\_\&`

Comment: That works for me. What is it not working on?

Comment: They only need to escape `-`. And even that not if they put it at the end or start of the character class. SmokeyPHP: What they have matches a lot more than what they want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the `-` at the end (or at the beginning) of the class if you want it to be considered as a *real char*:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_&-]+$/
```

You could also use the shortcut `\w`, which is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Thus:

```
/^[\w&-]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be shortened with `\w` (word character)

Try this regex:

```
var testexp = /^[\w&-]+$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex

```
/^[\w&-]+$/
```